# Pagamento parcelado com boleto via PagSeguro

Tags: php

Desenvolvi um site onde existe um curso para venda num valor específico. Este curso está disponível para pagamento com **PagSeguro**, para quem for pagar no cartão é tranquilo, mas teria alguma forma de fazer parcelado no boleto?

Até o momento, somente inseri um botão de doação, onde a pessoa que vai comprar o curso adiciona o valor conforme a possibilidade que pode pagar. O curso será somente final do ano, então dá para pagar em partes usando este recurso.

Pra facilitar mais ainda, só mesmo via boleto. Alguém sabe uma forma melhor(via boleto ou não) de fazer parcelas no *PagSeguro* sem ser no cartão?

Comment: Duas soluções alternativas ao PagSeguro para esse recurso de pagamento parcelado via boleto são o Vindi e iBuy (via cartão virtual).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que você tenha que configurar seu sistema para gerar mensalmente um boleto e enviá-lo para o comprador, já que o [pagseguro](/questions/tagged/pagseguro) não faz parcelamento em boleto.

> ## Posso parcelar o pagamento de uma compra através de Boleto
>   Bancário?
>
> Não. O Pagseguro oferece a opção de
>   parcelamento apenas para pagamento via cartão de
>   crédito.

Você também pode gerar vários boletos de uma única vez com datas de vencimento futuro, fazendo assim o "carnê" de pagamento com boletos gerados pelo [pagseguro](/questions/tagged/pagseguro).

Não sei se isso atende à sua necessidade, mas acredito que seja a alternativa mais viável.

Answer (score 4):

O PagSeguro não faz parcelamento no boleto. O que você pode fazer é utilizar a PHP Boleto (http://boletophp.com.br/) e gerar um boleto para cada parcela.
Esta biblioteca é simples de ser utilizada.